# Webservice method inside runnable in Android Service throwing Exception

Tags: android, web-services

I am trying to send battery information in regular intervals to my server.I already tested the webservice code and it is working fine without using Android Services but throws exception when I am trying to call webservice method inside runnable in Service.

**Though its working fine when I am trying to print Toast inside runnable in my Android Service.**

```
 package com.services;

    import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class BackService extends Service {
        private int m_interval = 20000; // 5 seconds by default, can be changed later
        private Handler m_handler;
        int  Level;

         private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xy.xy/insertfeedback";
            private static final String METHOD_NAME = "insertfeedback";
            private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://xy.xy/";
            private static final String URL = "http://192.168.9.2:8080/WebApplication2/NewWebServiceService?WSDL";
            SoapObject request;
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
            HttpTransportSE ht;

       @Override
       public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
          return null;
       }

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             request= new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       
             envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
             ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
       }

       @Override
       public void onDestroy() {
          //code to execute when the service is shutting down
       }

       @Override
       public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
             registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Stared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         m_handler = new Handler();
         m_statusChecker.run();
       }

       Runnable m_statusChecker = new Runnable()
       {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+ Level, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                BatteryService();
                 //updateStatus(); //this function can change value of m_interval.
                 m_handler.postDelayed(m_statusChecker, m_interval);
            }
       };


       private final BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
            Level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
             //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+Level+"%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }
           };


          public void BatteryService()
          {

              request.addPropertyIfValue("value",50);
              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


              try
              {
                  ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                  final  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                  final String str = response.toString();
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
               catch (Exception e) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of the Exception do you meet? You should post the Log too. It will help a lot find out your problem

Comment: I Don't know the exception its just going in catch. Probably this line is throwing exception.
ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

Comment: if you don't know the exception don't just catch it like this. Try to log the exception type and the exception message. This will give more insight in what is the actual problem.

Comment: its not working on the emulator but its working on the tablet.Thanks anyway.